# What SSD models and brands can I get for my Late 2012 MBP (MacBookPro9.1) that Yosemite supports?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, ssd

I've read that only the OWC one supports this but then again some people claim it's bogus.

So I was wondering what SSD brand and models I can get to upgrade my Late 2012 MBP that when I upgrade to Yosemite, it won't break as apparently if you have any non-Apple SSD, Yosemite will crash and display gray area due to kext signing.

I rather not get OWC one because even though everyone seems to swear by them, they don't have much review scores on sites like Amazon and rather go to more popular ones like Samsung 840 EVO, not only they are cheaper. But not sure if Samsung 840 EVO can work with kext signing.

Thanks.

Comment: Couldn't say for sure on a MBP, but I've an EVO 840 in my Mac Pro 08 & it's working just fine & dandy. Kext signing is at OS-level, not drive-level, btw.

Answer (score 1):

I personally can't tell you about SSD compatibility for MBP, but I went through the same process when I did a HD upgrade on my 2009 MBP. I found numerous reviews on sites like newegg, amazon, bestbuy and so on and many people said they used the drive to upgrade their MBP's. I ended up buying a HD from newegg that said it was for a MBP and it ended up not working for me. I then looked at OWC's HDs and bought an identical one on newegg with the same results.

The one that I ordered from newegg was the following: [WD Scorpio 750GB](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822136835)

The problems that I was having with the new HD's was that their connection would be intermittent. It would work for about a minute then everything would freeze for about 2 min then repeat. The HD itself was not failing because I tried it in an external enclosure attached to my mac and it work perfectly fine. The OS was not the problem and would install every time, but would take around 2 hours to install (normal install time was 30 min).

I ended up ordering a new one from OWC and worked perfectly in my MBP. One thing I noticed about OWC's HD was that there was a different firmware loaded on them specifically designed for apple products.

The specific HD from OWC is: [HGST 750GB (OWC)](http://eshop.macsales.com/item/HGST/0J12283/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks.

1) Would you please tell me what model did you order the 2nd time?

1) What do you mean by "not working", did you imply the Yosimite didn't install on it correctly?

3) Were you struggling with Yosemite install at all?

Comment: See my edits above.